# how the inherit happened in phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I just use Phaser and saw some example code like below. In the `Rox.Boot.prototype` function, the `.load`, `.physics`, etc, are all in `game(Phaser.Game)`. How does this inheritance happen?

```
Rox = {
    score: 0,
    music: null,
    orientated: false
};

Rox.Boot = function (game) {
};

Rox.Boot.prototype = {

    preload: function () {
        this.load.image('preloaderBar', 'images/preload.png');
    },

    create: function () {
        this.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        this.input.maxPointers = 1;
        this.state.start('Preloader');
    },
};
```

Comment: "this" used in preload and create functions refers to Boot. So there must be some code inside Boot function or it's intended to be added.

Answer (score 0):

To use Phaser, you have to have a phaser.min.js or phaser.js file which you can get [here](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/master/build).  I use the phaser.min.js file instead of the phaser.js file because I don't need the extra features that the phaser.js file has (debugging); phaser.min.js will have all the same methods, classes, properties, etc as phaser.js.

They tell you to download the whole GitHub repo, but really you just need the Phaser JS file.

After you add the phaser.min.js file to your project, make sure it's the first script you call in the head of your HTML file; you should be able to use Phaser in the following JS files after that.

Here is what my index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>FILL_IN_GAME_NAME_HERE</title>
        <script src="phaser.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
        <script src="Boot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Preloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="GameOver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="HighScores.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, Phaser.AUTO, 'game', false, false);
            game.state.add('Boot', Game.Boot);
            game.state.add('Preloader', Game.Preloader);
            game.state.add('Menu', Game.Menu);
            game.state.add('Game', Game.Game);
            game.state.add('GameOver', Game.GameOver);
            game.state.add('HighScores', Game.HighScores);
            game.state.start('Boot');
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```